# AngularJS arguments for directives - convention

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Simple question regarding arguments for AngularJS directives within markups. Let's consider the following markup that has it's own directive.

```
<div selectbox resource="http://resource.org/asset/1">
</div>
```

we are passing an argument called 'resource' - and it's ok, but just wanted to ask as it's recommended to use in HTML5 data-* prefixed attributes is it better to write

```
<div selectbox data-resource="http://resource.org/asset/1">
</div>
```

which convention is better and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better use custom html attributes with data- prefix, first of all it's described as standart for custom attributes and if you want to validate your html all custom attributes without data- prefix will be invalid.

From Angular Docs

> If you want to use an HTML validating tool, you can instead use the data-prefixed version (e.g. data-ng-bind for ngBind).

More info:

[Post about data-*](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/all-you-need-to-know-about-the-html5-data-attribute--webdesign-9642)

[Use with css3](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/05/using-custom-data-attributes-and-pseudo-elements/)